# Don't show Opencart filter in user side

Tags: filter, opencart, product

I am using opencart 2.0.1.1.

I tried to add filter in the product page.

Steps I followed:

```
 1. catalog > filter > add new filter 
 2. category > add filter
 3. product > add filter
 4. Enable filter module
```

But the filter is not shown in the user side in specified category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't do that already, go to System -> Design -> Layouts.

If you want the filter to show on the left column of each category go to Categories, click edit, create a new module, select Filters, then select the position (left, right, top, bottom). That should make it show up ;)